# Connecting to webserver running in docker in vagrant in vmware

Tags: macos, docker, vagrant, virtualbox, vmware

On my mac I am running Windows Server 2016 in VMware. In there I am running Ubuntu in vagrant/Virtual Box. In there I am running a django app in a docker container with nginx/uwsgi. The webserver is listening on 9003, and from a browser running in the Windows VM I can connect to the webserver with localhost:9003. I want to be able to connect to it from both a browser running on my Mac and from other machines on my local network. In the VMware network settings I have Internet Sharing, Share With My Mac selected.

In the Windows VM I see this:

```
$ ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter vEthernet (HNS Internal NIC):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a088:5807:8265:722%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.192.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::440c:bbeb:3408:87a2%6
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.88.128
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.88.2

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d90e:3f15:2ff3:9c8%3
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{128CE093-EDCD-4551-A68C-1ED0F721C48D}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C1972449-FA02-4CD9-A894-9F82BCD31099}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.localdomain:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
```

In the vagrant VM:

```
$ ifconfig
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:6a:c7:10:cf
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:6aff:fec7:10cf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:87179 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:177348 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:17368120 (17.3 MB)  TX bytes:1072352935 (1.0 GB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:ac:f1:24
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feac:f124/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:890873 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:128642 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1203867192 (1.2 GB)  TX bytes:24867499 (24.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1296 (1.2 KB)  TX bytes:1296 (1.2 KB)

vetha7780cb Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0e:7b:96:75:ae:68
          inet6 addr: fe80::c7b:96ff:fe75:ae68/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10063 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:13697486 (13.6 MB)  TX bytes:637891 (637.8 KB)
```

In the docker container:

```
# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.2  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10155  bytes 891257 (870.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5893  bytes 13702369 (13.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 506  bytes 184179 (179.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 506  bytes 184179 (179.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My Mac's local IP is 10.0.0.19.

From my Mac I tried connecting to localhost:9003, that did not work. And I also tried 10.0.0.19, 10.0.2.15, 172.17.0.1, 192.168.192.1, 172.16.88.128, and 192.168.56.1, both from my Mac and another machine on my local network. All did not work.

The firewalls on my Mac and in the Windows VM are both disabled.

How can I connect to this server from my Mac and other local machines?

UPDATE:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                   NAMES
87a9527a1a66        capgraph            "/opt/django/CAPgr..."   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 8006/tcp   capgraph
```

And in my Vagrantfile I have:

```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 9003
```

[image: VMware settings window]

[image: VMware VM menu]

[image: Network adapter]

Comment: Also add logs of `docker ps`

Comment: Updated with docker ps and also vagrant port forwarding.

Comment: A screenshot of your Windows VM network settings? This is from the VMWare VM -> UI Settings and not from inside the windows

Comment: Not sure what VMWare VM -> UI Settings is. I updated with screen shot of settings window and VM menu.

Comment: I want to inside the Network Adapter from your 1st screenshot

Comment: Added screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152391/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-larry-martell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another Network Adapter in your VMware settings and this should be Bridged with your Wifi Network, since you are using that.

This will allow your VM to have another IP in `10.0.0.X` series. And the app would be available on that `10.0.0.X:9003`